# Shade area between two curves with plotly.py

Tags: python, dataframe, plotly-python

How can I shade/colour the area between two curves in a `plotly.graph_objs.Figure` without at the same time plotting these curves?
Say I have a `pandas.DataFrame` named `df` like this:

```
                          Avg+Std       Avg-Std
Date                                           
2005-08-12 03:48:55  2.476648e+06  2.385271e+06
2005-08-12 10:00:00  2.483204e+06  2.385958e+06
2005-08-12 18:00:00  2.481905e+06  2.377431e+06
2005-08-13 02:00:00  2.544859e+06  2.432744e+06
2005-08-13 10:00:00  2.548977e+06  2.430185e+06
...                           ...           ...
2006-03-31 18:00:00  2.275795e+06  2.229585e+06
2006-04-01 02:00:00  2.232029e+06  2.184158e+06
2006-04-01 10:00:00  2.240574e+06  2.190765e+06
2006-04-01 18:00:00  2.265920e+06  2.214497e+06
2006-04-02 02:00:00  2.198642e+06  2.145292e+06
```

Then I can plot both columns as curves in a 2-dimensional coordinate system like so:

```py
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import plotly.express as px

### Import the DataFrame df
### ...

figure = px.line(
    df,
    title='area that should be shaded',
)
figure.show()
```

This gives the following output:
[image: The two lines between which I want to have shaded area]

How can I render the area between the curves gray (or shade/colour them in any other way)?

**My use-case:** Eventually, I don't want to plot the curves `'Avg+Std'` and `'Avg-Std'` anymore. I only want the shaded area.
But the figure will contain other curves. The shaded area will help to spot easily when those other curves leave the "normal area".

Answer (score 0):

- have simulated dataframe with *Avg+Std* and *Avg-Std* columns using sine curve
- have then created figure you note that you want where it is shaded gray between the two lines

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import math

df = pd.DataFrame({"Avg+Std": np.sin(np.linspace(0, math.pi * 8, 200))}).assign(
    **{"Avg-Std": lambda d: d["Avg+Std"] - 0.2}
)
px.line(df).for_each_trace(
    lambda t: t.update(fill="tonexty", fillcolor="lightgrey")
    if t.name == "Avg-Std"
    else t
).update_traces(line_color="rgba(0,0,0,0)", showlegend=False)
```

[image]